# React native redux-persist slices

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I am using the following [boilerplate](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/react-native-boilerplate/docs/ReduxStore/#architecture) with the following structure Redux store and Slices.

But I'm having some trouble making it work.

What I need to do is save some information such as: `language` and `type of theme` (light or dark).

So to be able to save, to be able to read them and to be able to overwrite information that is an object.

Now I did the following, inside [Store](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/react-native-boilerplate/tree/master/template/src/Store) I created a folder called `Settings` with the following files:

Settings/index.js:

```
import { buildSlice } from '@thecodingmachine/redux-toolkit-wrapper'
import InitSettings from './Init'

const sliceInitialState = {
  colorScheme: "light",
  lang: "fr",
  item: {}
}

export default buildSlice('settings', [InitSettings], sliceInitialState).reducer
```

Setting/Init.js

```
import {
  buildAsyncState,
  buildAsyncActions,
  buildAsyncReducers,
} from '@thecodingmachine/redux-toolkit-wrapper'

export default {
  initialState: buildAsyncState(),
  action: buildAsyncActions('settings/init', async (args, { dispatch }) => {
    console.log("Settings", args)
    // Timeout to fake waiting some process
    // Remove it, or keep it if you want display a beautiful splash screen ;)
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    // Here we load the user 1 for example, but you can for example load the connected user
    await dispatch({
      theme: "dark",
      lang: "it"
    })
  }),
  reducers: buildAsyncReducers({
    //errorKey: false,
    //loadingKey: false,
    //itemKey: 'item'
  }), // We do not want to modify some item by default
}
```

In Store's index.js file I did this, added `settings` and whitelisted it:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  persistReducer,
  persistStore,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import startup from './Startup'
import user from './User'
import settings from './Settings'

const reducers = combineReducers({
  settings,
  startup,
  user,
})

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: [settings],
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    const middlewares = getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    })

    if (__DEV__ && !process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID) {
      const createDebugger = require('redux-flipper').default
      middlewares.push(createDebugger())
    }

    return middlewares
  },
})

const persistor = persistStore(store)

export { store, persistor }
```

But it's not working, when I do this:

```
const st = useSelector((state) => state)
console.log(st.settings)
```

I am printed this in console:

```
{"colorScheme": "light", "error": null, "item": undefined, "lang": "fr", "loading": false}
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Information from the devtools would be useful such as: what actions are dispatched and what data do they have, what changes do the reducers make after the action was dispatched. If you can't get devtools running for native then maybe add middleware that logs the action and the state.

Comment: I am given a similar error: ERROR    A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload`. Value: [Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?] 
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  {"error": {"message": "Rejected"}, "meta": {"aborted": false, "arg": {"colorScheme": "dark"}, "condition": false, "requestId": "OExINHVwoC2nyJA-83gJV"}, "payload": [Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?], "type": "settings/init/rejected"}

Comment: (See https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants) 
(To allow non-serializable values see: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data)

Comment: s: {"colorScheme": "light", "error": [Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?], "lang": "fr", "loading": false}

Comment: A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `settings.error`. Value: [Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?] 
Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action type: settings/init/rejected.
(See https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [buildAsyncActions](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/redux-toolkit-wrapper/blob/master/src/wrappers/actions/buildAsyncActions.js#L4) calls to [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) and the payloadCreator should return a promise.

You could either just return a promise and not dispatch:

```
async (args) => {
  await new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000),
  );
  return {some:'value'}
},
```

Or dispatch a **valid** action:

```
async (args, { dispatch }) => {
  await new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000),
  );
  dispatch({
    type: 'SOME_TYPE', //you have to give the action a type
    theme: 'dark',
    lang: 'it',
  });
},
```

Comment: I am unable to get it to work, what should I put in your opinion: `reducers: buildAsyncReducers ({...})`

Comment: If I do this it seems to work: `return {colorScheme: args.colorScheme, lang:"fr"}`, but with dispatch I am not succeeding.